# Edit an XML-structure with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to convert an XML-file through a PHP-script. I have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persons>

<person id="1">
      <periods>3</periods>
      <name id="John"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="1"/>
          <time>35:28</time >
          <length>8000</length>
        </time>
        <time>
          <day id="4"/>
          <time>8:28</time >
          <length>2000</length>
        </time>
        <time>
          <day id="5"/>
          <time>3:03</time >
          <length>1000</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>

 <person id="2">
      <periods>3</periods>
      <name id="James"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="3"/>
          <time>45:20</time >
          <length>15000</length>
        </time>
        <time>
          <day id="5"/>
          <time>4:48</time >
          <length>1500</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>
etc…
etc…
</persons>
```

Every person has one or more time-elements. I want to convert the structure so I get only one time-element per person-element (like the structure below).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persons>
    <person id="1">
      <periods>3</periods>
      <name id="John"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="1"/>
          <time>35:28</time >
          <length>8000</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>

    <person id="1">
      <periods>3</periods>
      <name id="John"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="4"/>
          <time>8:28</time >
          <length>2000</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>

    <person id="1">
      <periods>3</periods>
      <name id="John"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="5"/>
          <time>3:03</time >
          <length>1000</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>

<person id="2">
      <periods>2</periods>
      <name id="James"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="3"/>
          <time>45:20</time >
          <length>15000</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>

<person id="2">
      <periods>2</periods>
      <name id="James"/>
      <times>
        <time>
          <day id="5"/>
          <time>4:48</time >
          <length>1500</length>
        </time>
      </times>
    </person>
</persons>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, just clone the node you want to duplicate, and alter the time nodes you delete from it (I'd use `DOMDocument` & a bit of `xpath` for this, but you could create and XSLT for this). However: your original structure seems a lot more workable then your desired output. Is there a special reason you need that output to be so?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes there is a reason. I need to convert it into JSON. It makes the JSON-code a lot more workable (for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really know English very bad, but I'll try to answer :)

I think, that for the implementation of this task will suit SimpleXml and Dom extensions.
The following is a simple script that does the required transformation.
input.xml is the file with source text.
The result of the algorithm will be saved to output.xml file.

```
<?php
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('input.xml'));
$personElements = $simpleXml->person;

$personForAppend = array();
$personsForRemove = array();

foreach ($personElements as $personElement) {
    $timeElements = $personElement->times->xpath("child::time");
    $numberOfTimeElements = count($timeElements);

    if ($numberOfTimeElements > 1) {
        $personDomElement = dom_import_simplexml($personElement);
        $backupTimeDomElementArray = array();

        foreach ($timeElements as $timeElement) {
            $timeDomElement = dom_import_simplexml($timeElement);
            $backupTimeDomElementArray[] = clone $timeDomElement;
            $timeDomElement->parentNode->removeChild(
                $timeDomElement
            );
        }

        while ($timeDomElement = array_shift($backupTimeDomElementArray)) {
            $copyPersonDomElement = clone $personDomElement;
            $copyPersonDomElement->getElementsByTagName('times')
                ->item(0)->appendChild($timeDomElement);
            $personForAppend[] = $copyPersonDomElement;
        }
        $personsForRemove[] = $personDomElement;
    }
}

foreach ($personForAppend as $personDomeNode) {
    $personDomElement->parentNode->appendChild($personDomeNode);
}

foreach ($personsForRemove as $personDomElement) {
    $personDomElement->parentNode->removeChild($personDomElement);
}
$simpleXml->saveXML('output.xml');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The output.xml file only shows the first time-element of a person. I would like to get one time-element per person like the structure in the second example (see above).

Comment: I apologize for my carelessness.I little bit changed the algorithm. I hope that is what you need.